# Error-Not enough storage is available to process this command When changing App Pool Process Identity

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

Running IIS 7.5 on Win2008. Trying to change the App Pool Identity to Administrator user. When I click OK on the dialog, I get this error: "Not enough storage is available to process this command. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070008)

I have tried IISRest and also Restart the sever But issue didn't fix.

Below is the error from Event Viewer

An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The object SearchDataAccessServiceInstance was updated by EDC2010-TEST\SPDatabaseConfig, in the OWSTIMER (1172) process, on machine EDC2010-TEST. View the tracing log for more information about the conflict.

Comment: First, IIS 7.5 is end of life. Try not to use it any more. Second, try to use appcmd command line to change the pool identity and it might report a more detailed error message than IIS Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Try to re-install IIS by using the server manager. According to Microsoft, this is a machine key corruption issue, which is used to encrypt and decrypt application pool identity credentials.
https://forums.iis.net/t/1180041.aspx
This is a Microsoft system-level problem, namely running out of interrupt request stack space, which can be fixed by making a registry change to allocate a larger `IRPStackSize`. It is discussed in the below link.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/106167/error-message-not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-c
https://appuals.com/fix-not-enough-storage-available-process-command/
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Answer (score 0):

This has solved the problem for me.
So I had a similar error and I could not find a resolve in any forums.
I'm using the "`WMI Provider Host`" to edit bindings in IIS using VBScript.
Anyways after trying a few suggestions such as `netsh http delete sslcert ipport=0.0.0.0:443` [Here](https://serverfault.com/questions/675518/an-error-occurred-while-using-ssl-configuration-for-endpoint-0-0-0-0443) and editing the registry `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\LanmanServer\Parameters > IRPStackSize` [Here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/106167/error-message-not-enough-server-storage-is-available-to-process-this-c).
I noticed when running my application the "`WMI Provider Host`" was getting to ±512MB in the ram and found that `C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv\config\applicationHost.config` was well over that size.
That's when I found [this link](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/ask-the-performance-team/wmi-high-memory-usage-by-wmi-service-or-wmiprvse-exe/ba-p/375491) to increase the memory allocation to the service.
Hopefully it helps.